# how to read the bash argument in that makefile

Tags: makefile

want to ask how to read the parameter if i start a makefile over bash like that:

```
make KU_II
```

### here my code

```
    CC            := clang++
    CCFLAGS       := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -g
    .DEFAULT_GOAL := help

    SECCHECK = SecChecks 
    INPUT         := $$1
    #.PHONY: bin run KU2 help
    .PHONY: SecChecks KU_II help

    INPUT         = $@ #Bezieht sich nur auf den Namen SecChecks: oder KU_II:

    vars:
    ifeq (${INPUT},"SecChecks")
      @echo "A"
    else ifeq (${INPUT},"KU_II")
      @echo "B"
    else
      @echo "NO" ${INPUT}  #test
      @echo "HIER:" $@     #test
    endif

    SecChecks: vars             ## Project 0: Security checks 
    @echo ${INPUT} " - ${INPUT}"
    @echo $1           #test

    KU_II: vars                 ## shopping list over vector products
    @echo ${INPUT}
    @echo $@

    help:                       ## prints the help text
    @echo "Usage: make \033[36m<TARGET>\033[0m"
    @echo "Available targets:"
    @awk -F':.*?##' '/^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?##.*$$/{printf "  \033[36m%-10s\033[0m%s\n", $$1, $$2}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
```

In the Makefile i need that KU_II as saved variable to work with it in if else sector, but how?

```
$@ is only for the .PHONY names as i figured out
$1 or $$1 doesnt work, and so on
$$? just 0 =/
```

With other words i need the equivalent to argv[] stuff with $1, $2. br, thx

Comment: What you seem to want is the actual *target* name that `make` will use? Otherwise I would recommend setting make variables, like `make KU_II INPUT=Something`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude make KU_II as argument / parameter at starting. that parameter / argument i want to use as example for INPUT. over INPUT := (CODE which i want to know) creates INPUT = KU_II

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to do that? What is the actual and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Please ask us about that problem directly, telling us about the solution you have tried. Perhaps there are other solutions to that original problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why do you need to know that for the answer? but ok. i want to sort over the variable the PATH = x/y/y variables. if i try to overwrite the variables with the same name I get allmost the last variables for PATH. see if else stuff....and dude. if you cant helt, dont write plz.

Comment: Here's the short answer to your direct question: you can't do that.  Makefiles are not shell scripts.  The arguments that you pass to make are not arguments that you can use in your makefile, they are _targets_ that you are asking make to build.  Make will take each argument and make sure it's up to date.  Now, if we understood what you really wanted to / why you wanted to treat the command line as arguments, we could probably explain how to do it (assuming it's possible at all).  But, you can't do what you're asking for here.

Comment: The reason I wonder about the original, actual and underlying problem is because without knowing it your question unfortunately is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). All we really can say now is that it's not possible to do what you want. If we know the actual problem, and you actually ask about it inside your question, then we might be able to help you solve that instead.

Comment: And if you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: @MadScientist now i will write that in C++ or python that hole thing. now i know why i didn't found any solutions / examples for that problem in the internet. make sence. thx

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it's not clear what you're actually after.   If you are trying to do something based on what targets were specified on the command line (and you don't care about other flags/variables specified), you could do something like:

```
vars:
    @echo $(MAKECMDGOALS) | grep -w -q SecChecks && echo "A"
    @echo $(MAKECMDGOALS) | grep -w -q KU_II     && echo "B"
```

The [`$(MAKECMDGOALS)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) contains all the targets specified on the command line.   So if you did `make a b VAR=value c`, then `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` would be `a b c`.  Note that it is possible for someone to specify both `SecChecks` and `KU_II` on the make command line at the same time.

Comment: Just to note this works with GNU make onlly: other versions of make don't support this variable.